# How to get states of multiple rendered component in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a mobile app with react native. I have a component "Period" which has a couple of TextInputs, each TextInput is stored as state. This component gets rendered in a flatlist multiple times. Now I wonder how i can get the state values of each instance of "Period" that gets rendered in Flatlist?

Any Explanation how this works in React Native. I thought every component instance has its on states?

Thanks alot

Comment: You can add a callback prop to Period that will send the text input's on change data back to the flatflist component, then store it all there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put all your inputs states and onchange functions callbacks in the parent component containing the ***Flatlist***, then you can pass your states as props to children components "**Period**"s.

I would suggest also working with a library such as [**Formik**](https://formik.org) to handle dynamic forms with multiple inputs